# How to use CONCAT in join sql request in ZF2

Tags: sql, zend-framework2

I am moving my zf1 app to zf2 and I am having a lot of problems to move my mappers.
Apparently, I can't just copy/past my query (too bad!)

I am trying to use `CONCAT` in a join like

```
$resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) use($userId, $filter, $status){ 

 $select->columns(array("id_project", "name", "current_to", "avancement"));
 $prj = "PRJ_";
 $select->join(array("ru" => "role_users"), "CONCAT( $prj , projects.id_project ) = ru.element", array())
                   ->where("ru.user_id = $userId");
```

If I print the `$select->getSqlString()`, I get :

```
    SELECT "projects"."id_project" AS "id_project", "projects"."name" AS "name", 
    "projects"."current_to" AS "current_to", "projects"."avancement" AS "avancement" FROM 
"projects" INNER JOIN "role_users" AS "ru" ON "CONCAT"( "PRJ_" "," "projects"."id_project"
 ) = "ru"."element" WHERE ru.user_id = 3
```

Apport for all the " ", this is correct (If I remove all the "" and execute it in phpmyadmin, it works.
But, if zf2 is executing it, I get an error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '`projects`.`id_project` ) = `ru`.`element` 
WHERE ru.user_id = 3' at line 1
```

It looks like there is a problem with the `CONCAT()` but I can't find where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This I find not very elegant but it works:

```
$select->join(array("ru" => "role_users"), 
new Expression("CONCAT( $prj , projects.id_project ) = ru.element"), array())
->where("ru.user_id = $userId"));
```